# How to run python scripts from windows gui?

Tags: python

I have installed Python2.7 on my Windows machine. How do I execute a file.py from windows GUI?

Comment: What happens if you double click the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should have python IDLE GUI if you downloaded the pakcage from python official site.
http://www.python.org/download/
select Python 3.2.3 Windows X86-64 MSI Installer .

you will have IDLE after intalling .

open IDLE . then go to File>open and select your .py file. a window will appear with the source code pf the file.
on the menu bar,select RUN. (or F5) .that is it!

Answer (score 1):

From whichever directory you are in, type the path of the python executable and the filename after that. That should do the trick.